# Firebase - Firestore, web server access only

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I think I’m missing something in all the Firebase/Firestore information out there. I’m creating a website using Firestore as the backend. The website offers some areas for user input, and the database needs to be updated based on that input. I see how to create rules for authentication levels, but how do I block all requests that don’t come from my web server?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

For those who stumble upon this, please note that I found that I should be using the Admin SDK for what I described. Be aware that if you go this route you must have some sort of backend in place, the Admin SDK does not work on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security rules don't have any control over the origin of a given request.  In fact, there is no way to control the origin of a request with Firestore, unless you want to try to set up a complicated VPN situation for all of your clients to use.

You should be thinking of security rules in terms of *who* can do *what* with the data in Firestore.  Not *from where* they can do these things.

Comment: Thank you for this answer because it quickly lead me in the right direction. Digging back through the docs I found the Firebase Admin SDK, which is exactly what I want. I basically want to connect using some sort of secret key rather than traditional auth. https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup